# Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined

Tags: webpack, sass-lint

I`ve got uncaught error, after connecting [sass-lint-webpack](https://github.com/alleyinteractive/sasslint-webpack-plugin) to *webpack.config.dev.js* from [Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Simply add this to *webpack.config.dev.js*:

```
const SassLintPlugin = require('sass-lint-webpack')
```

[image: require sass lint plugin]

and

```
new SassLintPlugin()
```

[image: connect sass lint plugin to webpack config file]

and then after run `yarn start` - I've got the error: *"Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined"*

[image: uncaught error after add sass lint plugin to webpack config file]

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

So you’ll need to install the plugin specifying the version when installation with npm :

```
npm install --save-dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugin outdated, use https://github.com/swordray/sass-lint-webpack instead, it is up to date with new webpack infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for turning your attention, I was wrong in writing the question, pointing out the wrong githab plug-in. I pointed **sasslint-webpack-plugin** instead actually use **sass-lint-webpack**

Screenshot:
https://s.mail.ru/DAxs/o8yn9wEyr

Comment: Anyway, I found a new plugin: **stylelint-webpack-plugin** and I'll try to install it now

Comment: Now I understand why someone put me a minus - because of my mistake, I pointed abandoned plugin in my question